# Changing Text into dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a big grid of values. At first, each values was a drop down. But it was very slow to load (+15 sec). 
So I would like to use text in my grid (a regular table ) and use a dropdownlist on the double click of the text . 
Is this possible ?
Also, is it possible to use a telerik drop down ?

Here's an example : A grid containing color (ex: blue, blue, red, yellow....). 
When double click on the word, a dropdown will replace the selected text. The dropdown will contain all available color : blue, red, yellow. After that, when the value is selected, the drop down would disapear and the text will display the new value.

So far, I got this :

```
$(function () {
    $('.colorGrid').dblclick(function () {
         debugger;
        $(this).html("<select class=\"resultMenu\" id=\"resultMenuID\" size=\"1\"></select>");
        $(this).children("select").append('<option value=1>Black</option>');
        $(this).children("select").append('<option value=2>Red</option>');
        $(this).children("select").append('<option value=3>Blue</option>');
        $(this).children("select").append('<option value=4>Yellow</option>');
    });
    $('#resultMenuID').change(function (event) {
        debugger;
        $(this).html("<td>test</td>");
    });
});
```

I'm close to my goal. Now I need to put back the result of the selected in a td tag, and the select must disappear! The change select function is never call. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you show us your html and javascript at the moment?

Comment: basic idea is to put all the 'stuff' of the potential dropdown into a block and hide it and add onClick to each such a block which will change value from hidden to visible. Then if you want to reduce load time, just make a block load appropriate values on user click on the block

Comment: MrOBrian, I just post this question today ?!?!?! Also, I don't see why I would send javascript example, the answer should be pretty generic. Why would you look at my other questions ? I didnt get any good answers to my other questions... so ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it takes +15 seconds, then you definitely have to go for `AJAX` or `hardcoding the dropdownvalues in javascript strings.`

As told by MrOBrian, I can't provide you the code solely based on your one or two line problem. You have to upload your existing problem code to get a solution from here. However I can give you an idea.

Say this is your colour block

```
<div id="colour-block-list">
    <div id="red-block" class="colour-block">
    Red
    </div>
</div>
```

You have to add an onclick handler.

```
$(".colour-block").click(function(){

  //call your ajax or get values from hard coded javascript string
   $(this).html("<select></select>");
   $(this).children("select").append(list_of_options);


});
```

Comment: Hi Afrin. This is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't provide code because it would take time to explain everything. The color example is similar to what I want. One more thing, how would you have a telerik drop down instead of the regular select in your example ? Also, when the user select his value, how would you put back the text format ? Thks

Comment: I got close to my goal. Now I need to put back the result of the select in a td, and the select must disapear!

Comment: @alex - you can do one thing. $(".colour-block").children("select").val() will get u the value. add this to the div. THen hide it for ALL the blocks. 

Do this on the click() handler. this way, before you service a click. values of all select blocks will be put into the td. then hide the td.